# The contenation 2 or more variable of variable variables

Tags: php, string, variables, combinations

i setup 2 set contenation of 3 variable. the first set i get from post. the second set i get from database.

the code

1st set

```
$code = $_POST['code']; //A0001
$det1 = $_POST['det1']; //it something v1
$det2 = $_POST['det2']; //numero uno
$alid = $_POST['al_id'];
```

2nd set

```
$sql = $conn->prepare('SELECT al_code, al_det_in, al_det_en FROM al where al_id=?');
$sql->execute([$alid]);
$stmt = $sql->fetch();

$alcode = $stmt['al_code'];  //A0001
$aldet1 = $stmt['al_det_in']; //it something
$aldet2 = $stmt['al_det_en']; //numero uno
```

the contenation

```
$$valA = $code . $det1 . $det2;
$$valB = $alcode . $aldet1 . $aldet2;
```

then i want to compare $$valA and $$valB in this code

```
if( $$valA === $$valB ){
  //do A
}else{
  //do B
}
```

but it always give wrong response, so i tried to echo

```
echo $code ." $$ ". $det1 ." $$ ". $det2 ."$$". $$valA ." $$<br>";
echo $alcode ." ## ". $aldet1 ." ## ". $aldet2 ." ## ". $$valB ." ##<br>";
```

the result is

```
A0001 $$ it something v1 $$ numero uno $$ A0001it somethingnumero uno $$
A0001 ## it something ## numero uno ## A0001it somethingnumero uno ##
```

i already tried to googling some answer but none similiar to my case. if it has been already answer to this case. hope someone can link the thread.

Edit
On nick suggestion i tried on https://3v4l.org/

```
$code = "A0001";
$det1 = "it something v1";
$det2 = "numero uno";
$alid = "01";

$alcode = "A0001";
$aldet1 = "it something";
$aldet2 = "numero uno";
$alid2  = "01";

$valA = "";
$valB = "";

$$valA = $code. $det1. $det2;
$$valB = $alcode. $aldet1. $aldet2;

echo $code ." $$ ". $det1. " $$ " .$det2. " $$ " .$$valA. " $$\n";
echo $alcode ." $$ ". $aldet1. " $$ " .$aldet2. " $$ " .$$valB. " $$\n";
```

the output

```
Output for 7.2.11 | took 27 ms, 15.1 MiB
  A0001 $$ it something v1 $$ numero uno $$ A0001it somethingnumero uno $$
  A0001 ## it something ## numero uno ## A0001it somethingnumero uno ##
```

so it replicate. i tried switch the order of $$valA and $$valB the result is that was the problem. so anyone know how to set up $$valA and $$valB properly?

Comment: I can't replicate your problem. https://3v4l.org/WkPtK

Comment: i use apache 2.4 and php 7.2 ts. i want to know that your result is correct one. not missing the v1 on the $$valA?

Comment: 3v4l.org isn't running PHP in Apache (see [about](https://3v4l.org/about)) but the code was run on PHP 7.2 in that demo and does not exhibit the problem.

Comment: I suspect `$det1 = "it something v1";` V1. Due to that string not getting any match.

Comment: based on https://3v4l.org/EVl35. it was $$valA and $$valB being the culprit. i tried ${$valA} / ${$valB} problem still exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case the variable variables `$$valA` and `$$valB` are in fact the *same* variables, because you initialised `$valA` and `$valB` (with one dollar) to the same string -- they are both the empty string.

So when you write:

```
$$valA = $code. $det1. $det2;
```

You are saying "assign to a variable whose name is the empty string the value `$code. $det1. $det2;`.

Then you do:

```
$$valB = $alcode. $aldet1. $aldet2;
```

Which means: "assign to a variable whose name is the empty string the value `$alcode. $aldet1. $aldet2;`

So in both cases you assign to the *same* variable (the one whose name is the empty string). So the second assignment overwrites the result of the first assignment.

Although you have two variable variables, they are just different notations to access the same variable. So at all times `$$valA == $$valB`, whatever assign to (one of) them.

From the code it is not clear why you would want to use variable variables. Just assign to `$valA` and `$valB` instead, and the `if` will work as expected. If you really want to work variable variables, then make sure `$valA` and `$valB` are different.

Comment: thanks, just put in $valA and $valB it works. i just want to try variable variables. but when i tried initialize $$valA and $$valB, it would return error like in https://3v4l.org/j4pF9. that way i initialize $valA and $valB.

Comment: In that link you never initialise `$valA`, which is a requirement before you can start using `$$valA`. The core question really is: why do you want to use variable variables? Be aware that `$$valA` is not a normal variable, it is a "variable variable" because of the double dollar. You should in fact never use it, It is bad practice any way.

Comment: the result is same as my code above, you can see in this link https://3v4l.org/BaTSl

Comment: What surprises you in that code? It works like I explained in my answer.

Comment: i agree that used simple contenation is the answer. i mean when use 2 variable variables it would overwrite variable variables before. even if you already initialize it $valA and $valB like in like https://3v4l.org/BaTSl

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, but I suppose you are OK with it?

Answer (score 0):

This bug happens because you are misusing the variable variables feature.

This feature means that the variable variable will read the variable and search the contents of it for a name that matches any other variable.

For example

```
$theoriginal = "I am the original variable";
$thenew = "theoriginal";

echo $thenew; // output: theoriginal
echo $$thenew; // output: I am the original variable
```

You are assigning empty values to your variables, and then declaring explicitly a variable variable and trying to force-adding variables to it. You are just misusing the feature.

Edit: since your code doesn't use dinamically modified variable names (at least as far as I can see on the code you shared) you can just concatenate the variables in a regular string variable and avoiding extra steps that are not required. (Once again, this is my opinion based on the code that I can see here, I do not know the rest of the code or if it does need that extra feature)

Comment: so that how to setup. in php manual $a = 'hello'; then $$a = ' world'; output is hello world. so i miss interpret that one. So basically if we setup $$valA = 'Hello A'; then $$valB = 'Hello B'; is suppose same variable. then $$valB overwrite the $$valA

Comment: The `$a = 'hello'` and `$$a = 'world'` means that, first, the variable `a` is created, and then a new variable is created using the contents of `a`, that's why `$a $$a` is equal to `$a $hello`, when you declared `$$a` you were just creating the variable `$hello`, something that will also be equal to `${$a}` that in facts means `$hello`.